# How to display all records from table by taking a tablename from another table?

Tags: mysql

i need to display  all records from table by taking table name from another table i used  below query to get that but i couldn't  get the expected result  here below is the query

```
SELECT * FROM (select distinct src_table_name from request_table) ;
```

and here is my request table below

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   src_table_name     |     src_col_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
test                           eno  
test                           ename  
test                           gender  


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and my test table is

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
eno    |    ename    |    gender
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          jack           m
2          dude           m
3          crop           m
4          pert           m
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and here i want to to display all records of test table by getting table name
**test** from request table..how can i achieve this? plz help me...

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - although this looks more like a problem of poor design

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a variable for a table name in a query in the SQL language. You Can't Do That™.

You need to ...

- use a host language (php, java, ??) to retrieve your table name and then construct your queries, or
- use [MySQL's built-in flavor of prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) in a stored procedure or some such approach.